# Find total user posting per post SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

I have a Database with the following two tables, member, POSTS I am looking for a way to get the count of how many posts a user has.

[image]
(*Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDv31.png*)

I have tried many variations of the following SQL command with out any success. instead of showing the count of posts for a single user it shows a single row with all the posts as the count.

In the end I want something like this

[image]
(*Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbaEj.png*)

Comment: Why you want to get `Blake` two times?

Comment: It's better to have your tables in the question itself, so we don't have to follow the links and can copy/paste the tables if necessary... (Like it was before you edited in the links).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be that I'm missing something here, but this query would seem to give you the results you want:

```
SELECT member.ID,
       member.Name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE member.ID = Posts.user_id) AS total
FROM   member;
```

I have left *comment* out of the query as it is not obvious what comment you want to be returned in that column for the group of comments that is counted.

See a SQL Fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f00a8/3).

**Edit**
Sorry, misinterpreted your question :-) This query will properly return *all* the comments, along with the person who posted them and the total number of comments that the person made:

```
SELECT Posts.ID,
       member.Name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE member.ID = Posts.user_id) AS total,
       Posts.comment
FROM   Posts
INNER JOIN member ON Posts.user_id = member.ID
GROUP BY Posts.ID, member.Name, member.ID, Posts.comment;
```

See an updated SQL Fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f00a8/9).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to calculate the total posts per member:

```
select  m.ID
,       m.Name
,       coalesce(grp.total, 0)
,       p.comment
from    member m
left join
        posts p
on      p.user_id = m.id
left join
        (
        select  user_id
        ,       count(*) as total
        from    posts
        group by
                user_id
        ) grp
on      grp.user_id = m.id
```

Comment: I think you forgot a _group by user_id_ clause in the grp selection (it's giving me an error when I try to run your query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f00a8/16)).

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   a.id
   , a.name
   , count(1) over (partition by b.user_id) as TotalCountPerUser
   , b.comment
from member a join post b 
on a.id = b.user_id
```

Comment: The _order by b.user_id_ in your OVER clause gives me an error in SQL Server, I think you might want to take it out of the query?

Comment: thanks : ), changed , still dont know why it would cause an error , it worked fine at mine sql server ;/

Comment: Might be a version difference then... Now it works. Neat solution by the way!